# ASP.NET Core 3.0 ConfigureApplicationCookie outside of ConfigureServices

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

When setting the cookie ExpireTimespan in ConfigureServices it works perfectly. However, I would like to get the timespan from the database so I thought I would move it to Configure. I can read the value of `IOptions<CookieAuthenticationOptions>` just fine and I can set it but it does not appear to work.

So this will work:

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    // Cookie settings
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);

    options.LoginPath = "/Identity/Account/Login";
    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Identity/Account/AccessDenied";
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
});
```

But this doesn't. The value gets set but the cookie won't expire:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ApplicationDbContext db, IOptions<CookieAuthenticationOptions> options)
{
    var settings = db.Settings.First();
    if (settings.ExpireTimeSpan != TimeSpan.Zero)
    {
        cookieoptions.Value.ExpireTimeSpan = settings.ExpireTimeSpan;
    }
```

What am I doing wrong? Does `IOptions<CookieAuthenticationOptions> options` need to be applied in some way? I tried it at the start and the end of the method.

Comment: The main difference between the two approaches is that `ConfigureApplicationCookie` configures a _named_ instance of `CookieAuthenticationOptions` (using the `IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme` constant). The `IOptions<CookieAuthenticationOptions>` injected into your `Configure` method isn't named, so it's affecting a different instance.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks, that makes sense! If you write that as the answer then I can mark it as answered. Just need to try it out.